# I need to export users from multiple OU to Respective OU names CSV's

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a script which will collect the users who haven't logged in before jan 2018 list and out put in single CSV.

I need the output like OU1 users output goes to ou1.csv, ou2 users output goeas to OU2.csv.

Here below script i have.

```
$Today = (get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy)

$OUs = (Get-Content E:\DATA\Password lastset before jan 2018\OU.txt)
foreach ($OU in $OUs)
{

  Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase $OUs -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,distinguishedname,cn,PasswordNeverExpires,passwordlastset,LastLogonDate,EmailAddress |
  where{ $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where{$_.passwordlastset -le ((get-date).adddays(-90))} |
  Where{ $_.LastLogonDate -le ((get-date).adddays(-240))} |
  select samaccountname, Displayname, 
@{n='ParentContainer';e={$_.distinguishedname -replace '^.+?,(CN|OU.+)','$1'}},@{Name="PasswordAge";`
Expression={((Get-Date)-$_.PasswordLastSet).days}}, @{N="LastLogonDate";E={$_.LastLogonDate}},@{n="EmailAddress";E={$_.EmailAddress}} |
  Export-CSV "E:\DATA\PasswordPolicy\ADUser lastlogon on or before Jan 2018 report-$Today.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

}
$Body = "ADUser lastlogon before Jan 2018"

Send-mailmessage -to "xxxx@xxx.com" -from xx@xx.com -SmtpServer usvasmtp -Body $Body -subject "OU1 ADUser lastlogon on or before Jan 2018 - Report For $Today" -Attachments "E:\DATA\PasswordPolicyEmail\OU1-$Today.csv"

Send-mailmessage -to "xxxx@xxx.com" -from xx@xx.com -SmtpServer usvasmtp -Body $Body -subject "OU2 ADUser lastlogon on or before Jan 2018 - Report For $Today" -Attachments "E:\DATA\PasswordPolicyEmail\OU2-$Today.csv"
```

Comment: Welcome as a new uswr to serverfault.com. You should take the [tour] and read [ask]. A description of your ou.txt format is missing. Also when iterating `$OUs` you should usse the current item `$OU` not the plural. Instead of concatenating multiple where, use a single one `-and`ing the conditions. When having problems/errors with your script; you should express them with error messages.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the inputs.. let me try and keep post you the results.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Export-CSV "E:\DATA\PasswordPolicy\ADUser lastlogon on or before Jan 2018 report-$Today.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

With:

```
Export-CSV $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Add:

```
$path = "E:\DATA\PasswordPolicy\" + $ou + ".csv"
```

at the stat of the foreach loop

if you specify the full DN inside your OU.txt, then you could use something similar like `$($ou.split("ou=")[-1])`
also fix your Searchbase: `-SearchBase $OU`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the inputs sure let me try and keep post you.